# d3js (+crossfilter/dc) boxplot performance

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I'm trying to use a combination of D3, Crossfilter, and DC generate interactive boxplots, mainly using this example: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/box-plot.html

My data looks more like this:

```
id      date        met1
6368    10/24/2013  0.84
6369    10/24/2013  0.67
6374    10/24/2013  0.96
6375    10/24/2013  0.97
```

with around half a million data points, which works fine for everything else except for the boxplots. The code works fine and the boxplots are fine, but when I change the filter elsewhere it takes forever for the boxplots to update:

```
var met1Dim = data.dimension(function(d) {return "metric 01";});
var met1Values = met1Dim.group().reduce(
            function(p, v) {
                p.push(v.met1);
                return p;
            },
            function(p,v) {
                p.splice(p.indexOf(v.met1), 1);
                return p;
            },
            function() {
                return [];
            }
```

Performance is drastically improved (but still not exactly ideal) when I pass integers as the data (just by replacing v.met1 with parseInt(v.met1 * 100)), but that's sort of half-assed and I'd like to display the data in their proper range, not by coercing everything into an integer. The most significant slowdown occurs when I'm removing datasets, and I think it's the slice(indexOf()) that's slowing everything down (when using floats). Is there anything I can do to make this operation faster? I was thinking maybe of an associative array using the id data is a key, but I'm not sure how to pass associative arrays into the reduce() function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a map lookup instead of `indexOf` will definitely help but it's still unfortunate that you need to jump through such hoops when all you really want as far as I can tell is to just do a basic grouping with the `met1` values showing up at the top level because that's what dc.js expects.

It would be very nice if dc.js allowed you to specify an accessor function that allowed you to define how you want the `met1` value pulled from the bound objects at the point at which it's needed.  d3 uses this pattern everywhere and it's very convenient (and also saves you from this kind of performance intensive juggling).

Barring this sort of change to dc.js, I think your idea for a map lookup is probably the best bet.  You can use the closure scope of your reduce functions to store it.  Since your records have unique ids you can just use a single map without needing to worry about collisions:

```
var indexMap = {};
var met1Values = met1Dim.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) {
        indexMap[v.id] = p.length;  // length before push is index of pushed element
        p.push(v.met1);
        return p;
    },
    function(p,v) {
        p.splice(indexMap[v.id], 1);
        return p;
    },
    function() {
        return [];
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your modification made the script run much faster. I was actually trying to incorporate the map into the reduce functions (like p[v.id] = v.dqc in the reduceAdd and reduceRemove functions) but couldn't get it to work. Your method is more intuitive and functional than that.

Comment: Update: I thought this solution worked, but apparently it does not (didn't notice with a large dataset). The boxplot function sorts the p array by value, so the indexMap mapping becomes incorrect. Also, when removing using p.slice, because the indexMap mappings are not updated with each removal, they become incorrect, as well. I will have to dig further for a solution. Thanks regardless.

Comment: Well, you won't be able to reuse the same indexMap across multiple reductions.  Each time you call group.reduce you should make sure that indexMap is empty.  In other words, indexMap is only used for the duration of a single group.reduce invocation.  Does that help with the problem you're describing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it would work if indexMap was emptied every group.reduce invocation. If it's simply emptied, how would indexMap be populated if I do multiple reductions in a row?

Comment: Actually, because you're using dc.js you're probably using the groups statefully so you're right this won't work.  (My normal usage is to dispose of groups and recreate them so I tend to start fresh with reduce on each pass).  Thinking about it, itstrikes me as odd that dc.js is doing the statistical calculations for the box plot itself.  Instead of feeding it in a huge pile of data, is it possible to calculate the stats yourself and feed it in just the min, max, median and so on?  I'm not familiar with dc.js so I don't know if that's possible or not.