# How to set y domain for dc js box plot? Does it handle negative values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Summary:

My doubts are regarding the dc.js box plot chart. I am not able to successfully set domain for the y axis of the chart. Also can box plot handle negative values?

In Detail:

I am getting an error on the console:

> Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="NaN"

Closer examination revealed that the problem is with the box plot indeed. The relevant code is given below:

```
alltwtssearchtrackdim = alltwtsndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.searchtrack;});

alltwtssearchtrackboxplotgroup = alltwtssearchtrackdim.group().reduce(
    function(p,v) {
        p.splice(d3.bisectLeft(p, v.sentiment), 0,v.sentiment);
        return p;
    },
    function(p,v) {
        p.splice(_.indexOf(p, v.sentiment, true), 1);
        return p;
    },
    function() {
        return [];
    }
);

boxplotsentiment 
.width(500)
.height(250)
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 30})
.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([-1.000, 1.000]))
.dimension(alltwtssearchtrackdim)
.group(alltwtssearchtrackboxplotgroup)
.elasticY(true)
.elasticX(true)
boxplotsentiment.tickFormat(d3.format('.3f'));
```

Now sentiment can vary from -1 to +1. Its the sentiment associated with tweets while search track is an ordinal variable. I checked the group. The value array and quartiles are calculated.

Problems that I am having:

1. Not able to set y axis domain between -1 and +1
2. The error I am getting on the console: Is it due to negative values?

Kindly help

Comment: I think negative values should be fine. The examples I've seen have used the .x() accessor rather than the y. Could also be a problem with your data. If you create a working example (using jsFiddle or a similar site), it would be easier to debug and help you.

Comment: I just added links to jsFiddle and bl.ocks skeleton examples on [the contributing page](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md#issue-submission-guidlines), so it should be easy to copy and paste your code into whichever system you're more comfortable with. Please let me know if these are helpful.

Comment: Let me try reproducing this. I am not very sure about sharing Twitter data. I will post the fiddle here once its ready.

Comment: Hi, Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yedurag/8arg0tf3/

Comment: Removing elasticY(true) eliminated the domain setting issue. The problems start when we apply filter on the donutsenti chart. I guess some arrays become empty when we do that.Again this may be a fault with the way I am handling the data. In that case I apologize for this question. Thanks.

Comment: Had a few typos. Here is the updated fiddle. The charts are working fine. But on clicking the 2nd donut chart we get errors in the console. https://jsfiddle.net/yedurag/8arg0tf3/3/

Comment: I found out a few more things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314722/d3js-crossfilter-dc-boxplot-performance - This solution seems to work without any error on the console. http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/box-plot.html - This solution and https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/543 - This solution gave the same error on the console.

Comment: It looks like the errors on the console are harmless, however they should certainly be fixed. Here is [the dc.js issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/628). It also appears in automated testing.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I had problems in fitting the y axis to the value extent when working with small numbers. Turns out [the y axis extent is too large on small numbers](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1120). In these cases, try setting

```
  .elasticY(true)
  .yAxisPadding('10%')
```

or some other sane value to [`yAxisPadding`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+yAxisPadding).